# Where did my Ether go?

Tags: transactions, etherscan

I'm quite new to Ethereum and might have lost my 0.046 ETH. Granted, not the biggest loss, however I'm trying to find out where I went wrong.

I downloaded the Aragon wallet, and got to a screen that told me, my balance was 0.

> In order to continue:
>
> Get testnet ether for your address (needed to transact), we are sending some but if it doesn't appear in your account in one minute, try here

It didn't appear, however my address did appear, so I went and bought some and sent a test amount. The transaction was a success (See [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd2f947b919395aa133979b3286df7c6b9319dba53e506d701e6a9556cf499fae)) but when I check the balance of the address (see [Etherscan](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0xc374c887995ac8ee1e7c9b43bbbf5ba099125fc8)) it's empty?

Comment: Hi there. Your first link shows a transaction to an address on the main public network. Your second link is to an address on the Kovan test network. These are two different chains. If you check the same address on the main network it shows your funds: https://etherscan.io/address/0xc374c887995ac8ee1e7c9b43bbbf5ba099125fc8.

Comment: Hey Richard, so it's safe to say my funds are lost, right?

Comment: Your money went to this new wallet
0xc374c887995AC8eE1e7c9b43bBbf5ba099125Fc8

Answer (score 1):

In Ethereum your private key can be used interchangeably between different networks, ie mainnet, kovan, ropsten, etc. But the balances for each network are independent.

Ask to the wallet developers how to export you private key, then you can import in another wallet that has support for mainnet and you should be able to have access to your funds.
>